# Can I use OpenMP and still manually control memory model?

Tags: c++, memory, openmp

I'm trying to learn OpenMP and wondering how much control I give up. In particular, when using openMP can I set memory model, can I avoid cache issues like false sharing between threads that openMP creates behind the scenes?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not giving up anything with OpenMP. You can basically chose whichever level of control you want. OpenMP gives you the option of doing things by hand if you want to... So what is that you want to do and that OpenMP doesn't automatically do the way you want it?

Comment: I've written parallel alpha-beta tree search which uses locks and I wanted to try lock-free but then thought maybe OMP way would be simpler.

Comment: If you want a lock-free implementation that is portable, then I suggest you to use C11/C++11 standard atomic library, which allows you to select the memory model and it's not hard to use.